# Apache Httpd backed by both Tomcat and PHP

Tags: server, apache2, php, tomcat

After a bit of googling it turned out that this topic is not well described hence asking about it here.

What I have already: well setup & working system where:

1. `Apache Tomcat` with main web-application is running on port 8080 and handling all requests like `mycompany.com:8080/*`
2. `Apache HTTPD 2.4.7` running on port 80 with PHP module and handling requests to WordPress-based blog at `mycompany.com/blog`

What I successfully achieved:

3. Adding `mod_jk` connector and having `Apache HTTPD` routing all requests to `Tomcat` via 8009 port so that Tomcat is handling all requests like `mycompany.com/*`

What I would like to achieve:

4. `Apache HTTPD` is intercepting all requests at port 80 and if url is `/blog*` then PHP5 module is intercepting it, **otherwise** everything else is handled by `mod_jk` connector i.e.

   /blog* -> PHP5 Apache module -> WordPress blog

   /* -> mod_jk -> Tomcat with web-application

Could you please advise if it's possible with minimum configuration of existing modules (without using modules like `mod_rewrite` or any other)?

Could you please elaborate regarding possible security holes of PHP module with such configuration since I'm not experienced with it?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Comment: **Another question:** please also advise if I should've posted this question to another `StackExchange` site since it's not directly related to `Ubuntu` itself (though server OS is indeed Ubuntu Server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered the same question on StackOverflow and got an answer there:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935328/php-wordpress-blog-and-tomcat-on-same-server-is-it-possible/30938420#30938420